# How does the Partition prob. have pseudo-polynomial runtime?

Tags: algorithm, code-analysis

I'm confused as to how the partition problem has pseudo-polynomial runtime and was wondering if anyone could help me out here. I understand that pseudo-poly time means that the algorithm runs in polynomial time wrt to the numerical value of the input but exponential in the size of the input. With the partition problem, the input is a set of integers (let's say of size n), so the size of the input is the number of bits required to represent all n integers. The partition algorithm runs in O(n*M) time, where M is the sum of (the absolute values) of the integers provided, but I don't see how to make the connection that this runtime is exponential in the number of bits from the input. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the number of input bits x.

Each input number will have O(x/n) bits.

Therefore the size of each input number will be O(2^(x/n)).

Therefore M will be O(n.2^(x/n)).

Therefore the algorithm will be O(n^2.2^(x/n)) which will increase exponentially as x increases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how did you get M as O(n.2^(x/n))?

Comment: If each number has x/n bits, then the largest it can be is 2^(x/n), so if we add up n of them, we will get a number less than n.2^(x/n).